# How to downsample or clear data from autogen retention policy

Tags: influxdb

I have implemented `CONTINUOUS QUERIES` and retention policies after our database has ingested a large amount of data. Namely I have `RETENTION POLICIES` and `CONTINUOUS QUERIES` for the following.

- The last year
- The last month
- The last week
- The last day

With the last day now being the default.

But of course I am left with the full resolution of data available in the default `autogen` policy. It appears I am unable to delete data on a per `RETENTION POLICY` basis. As such I would like to downsample the data I have in the `autogen` policy but am unsure of how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete data in a specific retention policy run:

```
USE "database_name"."retention_policy"
DELETE FROM "measurement"
```

This will delete all the data from `"measurement"` table in `"retention_policy"` RP which is currently active. To use default retention policy run `CLEAR rp`. It will reset active retention policy to default (`autogen` in your case).

Downsampling data from default RP into `last_day`:

```
CLEAR rp

SELECT MEAN(value)
INTO "last_day"."measurement"
FROM "measurement"
GROUP BY time(1d)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the retention policy of autogen to something very small, just large enough for your continuous queries to have the data available for downsampling.
e.g.

```
ALTER RETENTION POLICY autogen ON test DURATION 1h  SHARD DURATION 30m DEFAULT
```

Or you could set the autogen to 1d, as that is your shortest timespan and probably has full resolution anyway.